# Сглаживание анимации фона

Tags: html, css

Есть такой блок с фоном и эффектом:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/potw1441a.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 150%;
          background-size: 150%;
  
  transition: all 5.27s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover {
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
          background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> </div>
```

При наведении на блок, фон начинает дергаться и как-то с задержками изменяться.

Это можно как-то исправить (сгладить), если применять `transition` **именно** к **`background-size`** (со 150% до 100%)?

**P.S:** С `transform: scale;` я знаю решение, спасибо!

Comment: Подозреваю без `scale` никак. Насколько я понимаю в этом контейнере будет контент, но тогда можно фон закинуть в `:before` и его уже скэйлить )

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, Спасибо =))))) "С transform: scale; я знаю решение, "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы видите «дергание», потому что используете очень большое время анимации. Если поставить 1 секунду, анимация проходит гладко: https://jsfiddle.net/0c4mqLp8/.

Экспериментируйте с параметрами:
`all 5s ease` или `all 1s ease-in-out`, например. У меня оба варианта работают гладко.

Почему происходит скачки: ваша картинка выровнена по-центру блока. Изменяя масштаб, ширина картинки меняется то на четное, то на нечетное значение. Пиксель — самая маленькая единица измерения: центр делит картинку пополам и при четном значении картинка делится поровну, а при нечетном остается 0.5 пикселей, которые и придают дергание фоновому изображению — оно перемещается то влево, то вправо.

Comment: Возможно, моя объяснение ложное — это личная догадка.

Comment: Подергивание есть все-равно. Просто оно быстрее. Можно заметить если приглядеться.

Comment: `all 5s ease` меньше, но все же есть. Тоже как-то читала о задании округленного значения для `transition` (т.е. не 1.275, а 1), но тут что-то не помогает.

Comment: Можно попробовать `@keyframes`, указав нужные значения от 0 до 100% кадров. Но это раздует CSS в разы. Либо использовать дополнительно JS. Вот пример библиотеки (сам не пробовал): https://github.com/branneman/TinyAnimate#using-requirejs-changing-the-opacity-of-a-rgba-color. Можно попробовать перехватывать значение `background-size`, оборачивая его в, условно, `var size = parseInt(size, 10); if (size % 2 !== 0) { size += 1; }`, пропуская нечетные значения (или наоборот).

Comment: Я думаю правильней тогда будет сделать дополнительный блок в котором будем менять размеры самой картинки, а не фоновой. Можно будет использовать scale и т.д.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте поставить кривую Безье более плавную в начале и конце:

```
-webkit-transition: all 5s cubic-bezier(.6,0,.4,1);
transition: all 5s cubic-bezier(.6,0,.4,1);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Javascript не даст вам большей производительности, чем CSS**, т.к. трансформация в 
CSS производится с использование **аппаратного ускорения**.

Вот ресурс для генерации кривых Безье: http://cubic-bezier.com/#.6,0,.4,1

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: conten-box;
}

.box-c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/potw1441a.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 5s cubic-bezier(.6,0,.4,1);
  transition: all 5s cubic-bezier(.6,0,.4,1);
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.box:hover {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-c">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы тоже не прочитали задание. И js тут при чем, о нем вообще речь не шла

Answer (score 3):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: conten-box;
}

.box-c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/potw1441a.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.72, 0.71, 0.72);
  transition: all 5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.72, 0.71, 0.72);
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.box:hover {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-c">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Можно еще так попробовать как вариант

Comment: со `scale` я знаю решение!!! Вопрос был "transition именно к background-size?" Читайте внимательнее!